# asp.net MVC 3 equivalent of EmptyDataText

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC3, I am trying to:

return View(myitems.ToList());

If I am returning an empty list, I would like to display, "Items not found"...
is there an equivalent EmptyDataText as in asp.net forms?

Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you could test the model and act accordingly:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
}
else
{
    <div>Items not found</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried @if(Model.Count() > 0)...and that always = True.  Should I be getting the count of items or something else?

Comment: @Par6, if you are always getting True, it means that your model always contains items and is never empty.